# Does spring cloud stream support dynamic routing, which is rabbitmq feaure?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, event-driven-design

Is dynamic routing is same as dynamic destination binding in spring cloud stream ?

Dynamic routing as per rabbit all producer published to same queue, producer configured with routingKeyExpression and consumer listener configured with bindingRoutingKey and exchange routes the message to matched bindingKey.
does this can be accomplished using stream bridge or BinderAwareChannelResolver? If not how does spring manage with this in case someone wants to move from rabbit to any other broker.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be accomplished with `StreamBridge`, `RoutingFunction`, `spring.cloud.stream.sendto.destination` etc., depending on your use case which is not clear from your post, hence I am giving you everything.

You can find more information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.12.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_event_routing) and [here for StreamBridge](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.12.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources).

The `BinderAwareChannelResolver` is deprecated in favor of `StreamBridge`